# Extract a class from a module into a JAR

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I have an Android Studio module with many classes. To shrink the APK, I'd like to store a class in a JAR/AAR instead of including it in the APK.

This class depends on other classes in the module, so I can't place it in a separate Java library module. Using Gradle, is there a way to customize the build so that it stores a class in a JAR/AAR instead of including it in the APK?

Comment: You have to creat separate project as library and include it in your main project as library. If there is classes in main project you may have to move them to library project. You can't make jar separately when they depending on each other

Answer (score 0):

You'd still have to include the JAR/AAR in the APK for it to be able to compile and run, so i'm sorry, but this makes absolutely no sense to do.

There are many many other ways to shrink your APK.

1) Use Proguard to remove unused classes and functions.
2) Use Pngcrush (or similar) to reduce the size of your PNG's
3) Use Vector Drawables instead of PNG's
4) Enable ShrinkResources
5) Manually remove unused libs/drawables/code